# google map with jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm having problem to display map when its inside Jquery tabs.
Instead of seen the full map I see only small part of it.

I tried to follow another post here without any luck.

How can I fix that?

Thanks

Map code:

```
<div id="content_4" class="tab_block">

    <?PHP

        $pins .= "
                { 
                    address: '$address', 
                        html: { 
                        content: '<div>$fullName</div>', 
                        popup: true,
                    } 
                },  
                ";

    ?>
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 600px; 
            width: 600px;
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>            
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
    <script src="js/maps/jquery.gomap-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() { 
            $("#map").goMap({ 
            markers: [
                <?PHP echo $pins ?>

            ],
            maptype: 'ROADMAP' , //maptype: HYBRID, ROADMAP, SATELLITE, TERRAIN
            zoom: 11,
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>

    <div id='map'></div>

</div>
```

Tab code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// When a link is clicked
$("a.tab").click(function () {


    // switch all tabs off
    $(".active").removeClass("active");

    // switch this tab on
    $(this).addClass("active");

    // slide all content up
    $(".tab_block").slideUp();

    // slide this content up
    var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
    $("#"+content_show).slideDown();

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

When the map's container `div` changes size, you must trigger a `resize` on the map -

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
```

See the Events section for the Map object in the [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)